# How to combine/simplify these queries?

Tags: sql, select

I have these four SQL queries:

```
SELECT `a017kstatus` FROM `a017` WHERE `a017kstatus`='A' AND `a017kjantina`='L';    
SELECT `a017kstatus` FROM `a017` WHERE `a017kstatus`='A' AND `a017kjantina`='P';    
SELECT `a017kstatus` FROM `a017` WHERE `a017kstatus`='TA' AND `a017kjantina`='L';    
SELECT `a017kstatus` FROM `a017` WHERE `a017kstatus`='TA' AND `a017kjantina`='P';
```

How can they be simplified and in best case be combined to a single query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have it in mind to obtain a result set consisting of the result of all four queries, you could `UNION` them together.  But we can simplify even further using just a single query:

```
SELECT a017kstatus
FROM a017
WHERE a017kstatus IN ('A', 'TA') AND
      a017kjantina IN ('L', 'P')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you select the same field from the same table in each query, you just have to combine their `where`-clauses.

As a first step it would look like this:

```
SELECT a017kstatus
  FROM a017
  WHERE a017kstatus='A' AND a017kjantina='L'
    AND a017kstatus='A' AND a017kjantina='P'
    AND a017kstatus='TA' AND a017kjantina='L'
    AND a017kstatus='TA' AND a017kjantina='P'
```

But it can be simplified further by using the `in`-operator:

```
SELECT a017kstatus
  FROM a017
  WHERE a017kstatus in ('A','TA')
    AND a017kjantina in ('L','P')
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i need the result in different column. can u help me ?

Comment: Then you would need multiple joins. But that's another question. I answered the question you asked. You must not change the question significantly after it is answered. I recommend you to ask this question separately now.

Answer (score 0):

If one day you should extract different values of `a017kjantina`  for `a017kstatus` ('xx' is just an example):

```
SELECT a017kstatus
  FROM a017
  WHERE (a017kstatus ='A'AND a017kjantina in ('L','P') )
       OR (a017kstatus ='L'AND a017kjantina in ('L','P', 'xx') )
```

Answer (score -1):

Union should help you here:

```
SELECT a017kstatus FROM a017 WHERE a017kstatus='A' AND a017kjantina='L'
Union
SELECT a017kstatus FROM a017 WHERE a017kstatus='A' AND a017kjantina='P'
Union
SELECT a017kstatus FROM a017 WHERE a017kstatus='TA' AND a017kjantina='L'
Union
SELECT a017kstatus FROM a017 WHERE a017kstatus='TA' AND a017kjantina='P';
```

Comment: While `UNION` combines the queries to a single one, it does not simplify it in any way.